# how to make vaadin-drawer-toggle in vaadin-app-layout closed by default?

Tags: vaadin, lit-element

how to make vaadin-drawer-toggle in vaadin-app-layout closed by default?

```
<vaadin-app-layout>
 <vaadin-drawer-toggle slot="navbar"></vaadin-drawer-toggle>
    ......
```

Answer (score 3):

I think by adding `drawerOpened = 'false'` you should achieve that

```
<vaadin-app-layout drawerOpened = 'false'>
  <vaadin-drawer-toggle slot="navbar"></vaadin-drawer-toggle>
  ......
```

If you're using the Java API, you can use

```
AppLayout.setDrawerOpened(false);
```

Comment: it is strange but your advice didnt help, when page first load drawer still open

Comment: That's strange. Can you see the `drawerOpened` property set to false in the DOM?

Comment: Btw, if you are trying to achieve this within LitElement `render()`, then you should either use `<vaadin-app-layout .drawerOpened=${false}>`, or alternatively update the vaadin-app-layout component within a `firstUpdated()` lifecycle method

Answer (score 1):

The flow-AppLayout java API has a method 'setDrawerVisible(boolean)' (just in case)